# Xamarin forms Android - Is it possible to restore data on reinstalling the app using shared preferences or Secure storage?

Tags: xamarin

I am creating a sample Android application using Xamarin forms. I generate a unique ID randomly for that particular device when the User Install the app. I stored the value in Shared preferences/secure storage using Xamarin.Essentials just to check the persistence. It persists the data when I login and logout the app. But when uninstall and install the app, the data is not persisting, rather a new ID is created. Could anyone help me to solve this issue. I am not sure whether this can be achieved or something I am doing wrong. Do I need any additional setup to be done on the device?

Comment: Does the user have to sign into the app? If so, you save their shared preference info on the server, tie it to their login info, then when the user reinstalls the app and sign back in, the server would send down all of their preference data via API calls from your app. Another option would be to save a file somewhere in shared storage but I am not positive that would work and the file could be deleted between reinstalls

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the application will cause all Preferences to be removed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences?tabs=android

Answer (score 0):

If you want to permanently save user ID of that device, you need to store that key on a server once you first generate it. Shared preferences only works for client side and it is related to the memory of the app, once the app is uninstalled, shared preferences are cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences will get deleted once you uninstall the application.

However there could be 2 approaches for your scenario,

**Approach 1**

- Store a unique file with a unique name in some folder at a public location.
- Store the data in that file which you want to persist
- Re-sync data after uninstall and install from the file at a public location.

**Disadvantage** : It can be manually deleted by the user and in that case it would be considered a fresh install.

**Approach 2**

There are 2 kinds of ids identifiable for an android device.

> 1. Secure.ANDROID_ID
>
> This is unique per physical device. After boot of each android device,
> for the first time, a 64 bit random number is generated and maintained
> for a lifetime (unless the device was factory reset). After Factory
> reset it could change.

> 2. UUID
>
> This is a unique number for an app per installation. Every time your
> app is installed android generates this unique id per installation.

So, to address your requirement,

- No need to generate a unique random number per installation yourself.
  You can use UUID.
- After the application is installed, you can store a Secure.ANDROID_ID on your server and the all the data corresponding to that device which you want to persist in your database on server.
- On re-installation and the application start up those data can be re-synced using the ANDROID_ID.

**Disadvantage** : Upon Factory reset, the ANDROID_ID could change and it could be considered a fresh install.